# Dagger2 - null instead of injected object

Tags: android, dagger-2

For making things simple, suppose I want to inject EmailValidator from apache validators into my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Inject
    EmailValidator emailValidator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

I have a MainModule class:

```
@Module
public class MainModule {

    @Provides
    public EmailValidator providesEmailValidator() {
        return EmailValidator.getInstance();
    }
}
```

and MainComponent interface:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = MainModule.class)
public interface MainComponent {

    EmailValidator getEmailValidator();
}
```

When trying to use my validator in activity, I'm getting a nullpointer exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator.isValid(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Obviously I'm missing something. I know that dagger creates component implementation for me. Should I use it? How?

If I do the following in my onCreate method:

```
        emailValidator = Dagger_MainComponent.create().getEmailValidator();
```

then everything works fine.

But I want to be able to use @Inject annotation anywhere (probably on setter/constructor instead of a field) instead.

**What am I missing?**

I did something similar with dagger1 and it worked. Of course I needed to call `ObjecGraph.inject(this)` in activity. What's the dagger2 equivalent?

**EDIT:**

Ok, so I've found a solution. If anyone will ever have such a problem, there are some snippets:

1) I've created an application class:

```
public class EmailSenderApplication extends Application {

    private MainComponent component;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        component = Dagger_MainComponent
                .create();

        component.inject(this);
    }

    public MainComponent component() {
        return component;
    }
}
```

2) In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
        android:name=".EmailSenderApplication"
        ...
```

3) And finally, in the activity class where I want to inject some components those two ugly as hell lines:

```
component = ((EmailSenderApplication) getApplication()).component();
component.inject(this);
```

Comment: I can't call `inject` on my component. Also The Dagger_MainComponent syntax seems to have changed to just DaggerMainComponent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like you need to build your component as in:

```
component = Dagger_ MainComponent.builder()
        .mainModule(new MainModule())
        .build();
```

Typically, you do this in the `onCreate` method of your Application.

One good resource that may help you is the [example apps in the Dagger 2 repo](https://github.com/google/dagger/tree/master/examples).

I also found this PR helpful, from a [suggested update to Jake Wharton's u2020 sample app](https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020/pull/42/files) (from the main Dagger 2 Engineer). It gives a good overview of the changes you need to make when going from Dagger 1 to 2 and, apparently that's what [he points people to as well](https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020/pull/42#issuecomment-71062101).

Comment: I figured it out. Because of useful links, I'm accepting this answer :)

Comment: Glad you got it fixed! From your edits above, it looks like you had a case where none of your module constructors require constructor arguments. When that's true, the component will have a `create` method for you to use instead. Chances are though, after a while, you will need to pass your application in to one of those modules and when that happens, you'll have to fall back to using the builder as described, above.

Comment: Yeah, I know about it, but thanks. ;)
The missing part Was component.inject(this)

Comment: Could anyone explain why this is?  I corrected this in my app through trial and error but don't quite see the reasoning.  In my case, I had an activity that built the component and injected itself.  Then a Controller would have been injected to the Activity but was always null until I made another inject into the Component with the Controller as a param.

Comment: In my case, I have injected dependencies in my application object so I must inject. Your case sounds different but the good news is, since the code is generated, you can just trace through the particular `inject` call that you're asking about in the IDE and see *exactly* why it's needed.

Comment: first [link](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/examples/android-simple/src/main/java/com/example/dagger/simple/DemoApplication.java#L41) is broken, is there any replacement for it ?